# when the checkbox is checked allow one data for dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I want to know how to handle this using JavaScript. When I checked the ccheckbox of `IsPrimary` I will limit that dropdown data to become an unique value where it is the only one who is primary on that dropdown value.

[image]

So each of the values in Contact Type must have only one primary

This is my Cshtml

```
 <p>
            <label for="ddlContactType">
                Contact Type</label>
            <span>
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlContactType", new SelectList(ViewBag.ContactTypeList, "ID", "Display_Value", ContactType), "[Please Select]",
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"class"}
            })
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="txtContactValue">
                Contact Value</label>
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="txtContactValue" name="txtContactValue"  inputLong" value="" />
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkIsPrimary" id="chkIsPrimary" value="true" checked="checked" />
                <label>
                    Is Primary?</label>
            </span>
        </p>
```

I just want to validate on how will I limit the contact type value. I just need 1 IsPrimary every dropdown list data. For example I add one Email Address and the IsPrimary Checkbox is checked it will save then when I picked Email Address Again and checked the IsPrimary checkbox. There is a natification that only one IsPrimary in email address.

Thanks :D

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? I can't understand what are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery:

After adding class "isPrimaryCheckbox" to the IsPrimary checkbox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".isPrimaryCheckbox").change(function() {
      if($(this).prop("checked")) {
         $(".isPrimaryCheckbox").not(this).prop("checked", false);
      } 
   });
});
```

Every time one of the checkboxes is changed it checks if it has been checked - and if so unchecks all the others.

The same basic principle could be applied in pure javascript (without jQuery), but it would be more complicated.

Comment: i just want to validate on will i limit the contact type value. . I just need 1 IsPrimary every dropdown List data, Example i Add one Email Address and the Is Primary Checkbox is Checked it will save then when i picked Email Address Again and checked the Is Primary Checkbox , There is a Notification that only one IsPrimary in Email Address

Answer (score 0):

You could keep data in some hidden field. Than, when checkbox is checked you verify with `jquery` if `x` exists in your hidden field.

For example :

`<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;"></div>`

```
$("#mycheckbox").click(function(){

   if ($(this).is(':checked')){ 

      if( $("#mydiv").text() == "something" )
        -- do something --
 }  
});
```